# How to fetch one item at a time from an array and print them?

Tags: arrays, xml, powershell

Let us suppose that i have an array with 5 elements in it.

```
$fruits[$a] - {fox,apple,tiger,lion,rose}
```

i want these items to be fetched from this array and to be printed in an XML file in the following format :

```
    <elements>

    <elements scope="items">fox</elements>
    <elements scope="items">apple</elements>
    <elements scope="items">tiger</elements>
    <elements scope="items">lion</elements>
    <elements scope="items">rose</elements>

    </elements>
```

I am unable to fetch the data in the above mentioned format... instead by my script i am getting the elements in the following format (which is not required)

```
    <elements>

    <elements scope="items">fox apple tiger lion rose[0]</elements>
    <elements scope="items">fox apple tiger lion rose[1]</elements>
    <elements scope="items">fox apple tiger lion rose[2]</elements>
    <elements scope="items">fox apple tiger lion rose[3]</elements>
    <elements scope="items">fox apple tiger lion rose[4]</elements>

    </elements>
```

I've tried

```
For($a=0;$a -lt $elements;$a++) { 
  $arte[$a] = Split-Path $arte[$a]-Leaf $global:xmlWriter.WriteRaw("<elements scope="items">$arte[$a]</elements>") #Write-Host $arte[$a]; 
}
```

Comment: You should show the script you're using.

Comment: @GouravBid, I've added that to your post, but in the future just edit your post instead of posting it as a comment

Comment: @Chris - Below is the part of script i am using to get this done - 

    For($a=0;$a -lt $artefacts;$a++)
            {                
             $arte[$a] = Split-Path $arte[$a]-Leaf
             $global:xmlWriter.WriteRaw("<artefact scope=`"machine`">$arte[$a]</artefact>")
             #Write-Host $arte[$a];
            }

Comment: @DanField - can you please repost the comment. and sorry for the inconvenience but i am new to this site and still don't know how to format part of the codes in the comments...

Comment: There's an edit link under the tags in your post.  You should really post a bit more of your script - try reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve